# Using Excel Interop library with python3 ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes, excel-interop

I'm trying to write a wrapper library for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll by using Python3. Due to security policies I'm stuck with core python libraries, which has the [ctypes library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) for calling functions in DLLs and shared libraries. In other words **I'm not able to use win32com (pywin32)** which would probably be the most straight forward solution (I have already done this in past).

I have already written a similar library for C#. In C# I would use following Excel.cs program to create a Workbook:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
namespace ExcelSpace  {
    public class ExcelMainClass {
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main() {
            // Create a application instance
            Application excelApp = new Application();
            // Add a new workbook
            Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
            // Save the workbook into current directory
            workbook.SaveAs(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\MyNewWB.xlsx");
            // Close the workbook and application
            workbook.Close(0); workbook = null; excelApp.Quit();
            // Cleanup
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp); excelApp = null; GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
    }
}
```

I have copied the Excel Interop DLL to local directory from "C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c" to be able to reference it more easily. Then I would compile the program with csc.exe:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /r:Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll /out:Excel.exe Excel.cs
```

Now I would like to do similar program with python3 and ctypes. Based on [Access COM methods from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48986244/access-com-methods-from-python) and [How to use IFileOperation from ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62065891/how-to-use-ifileoperation-from-ctypes) I have figured out, that I have to get CLSIDs from my registery. Then I have defined GUID class similar to the comtypes [GUID.py](https://github.com/enthought/comtypes/blob/master/comtypes/GUID.py)

Here is the Excel.py program that I have written so far:

```
#HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Classes\CLSID\
#Assembly == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C
#Microsoft Excel Application - Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.GlobalClass == {00020812-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
#Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.OLEObjectClass == {00020818-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
#Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorkbookClass == {00020819-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
#Microsoft Excel Worksheet == {00020830-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}

import ctypes
from ctypes import *
import sys

##
# https://github.com/enthought/comtypes/blob/master/comtypes/GUID.py
##
BYTE = c_byte; WORD = c_ushort; DWORD = c_ulong
_ole32 = oledll.ole32
_StringFromCLSID = _ole32.StringFromCLSID; _CoTaskMemFree = windll.ole32.CoTaskMemFree; _ProgIDFromCLSID = _ole32.ProgIDFromCLSID;
_CLSIDFromString = _ole32.CLSIDFromString; _CLSIDFromProgID = _ole32.CLSIDFromProgID; _CoCreateGuid = _ole32.CoCreateGuid
class GUID(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("Data1", DWORD),
                ("Data2", WORD),
                ("Data3", WORD),
                ("Data4", BYTE * 8)]
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        if name is not None:
            _CLSIDFromString(str(name), byref(self))
    def __repr__(self):
        return u'GUID("%s")' % str(self)
    def __unicode__(self):
        p = c_wchar_p()
        _StringFromCLSID(byref(self), byref(p))
        result = p.value
        _CoTaskMemFree(p)
        return result
    __str__ = __unicode__
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, GUID):
            return cmp(bytes(self), bytes(other))
        return -1
GUID_null = GUID()
##

##
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48986244/access-com-methods-from-python
# and
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62065891/how-to-use-ifileoperation-from-ctypes
##
CoInitialize = _ole32.CoInitialize
CoUninitialize = _ole32.CoUninitialize
CoCreateInstance = _ole32.CoCreateInstance

rc = CoInitialize(None)
clsid = GUID("{00020812-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}")
drv = c_void_p(None)
rc = CoCreateInstance(byref(clsid), 0, 1, byref(clsid), byref(drv))
''' Pointers manipulation. Short form: function = cast( c_void_p( cast(drv, POINTER(c_void_p))[0] ), POINTER(c_void_p)) '''
VTable = cast(drv, POINTER(c_void_p))
wk = c_void_p(VTable[0])
function = cast(wk, POINTER(c_void_p))

#Unload DLL and reset COM environment
rc = Release(drv)
rc = CoUninitialize()
```

The CoCreateInstance function gives me following error:

```
    rc = CoCreateInstance(byref(clsid), 0, 1, byref(clsid), byref(drv))
    File "_ctypes/callproc.c", line 948, in GetResult
    OSError: [WinError -2147221164] Class not registered
```

I have no idea why I get this error message. I also don't understand based the other Stack overflow questions, that I have linked to this question, how I can create the Excel Application instance. Should I use [ctypes load shared libraries functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes-loading-shared-libraries) to load the DLL at some point?

There might be some way to write static functions with C# and then call them from python more easily, but I would consider this as dirty solution, and I would like to stick with pure python code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually have Excel installed?  You don't have to do this with the GUIDs.  You can say:

```
import win32com.client
excel = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Workbooks.Add()
... and so on ...
```

Comment: As I said in the very beginning of my question, using win32com is not an option.

Comment: Duh, I skipped right over that.  May I ask why not?  It is by far the best solution.

Comment: Libraries outside the Python Standard Library are a security threat and therefore are not allowed. [For example](https://dailyuknews.com/tech/python-package-index-nukes-3653-malicious-libraries-uploaded-soon-after-security-shortcoming-highlighted/). Also from personal point of view, I'm interested to understand how COM interfaces work under the hood.

Comment: Sorry, that's complete nonsense.  You have source code for ALL of these external libraries.  ALL of them.  Security is not an issue.